# bootbox confirm popup box doesn't appear and the page freezes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, bootbox

The regular js confirm popup box works but when i switch to the bootbox format the page freezes. I've installed the latest version of bootbox and bootstrap via package manager console. I've looked at tutorials and followed the exact some steps but happen to face the same issue. I'm not sure if I've explained the problem all that well as i'm new to this.

Here's my code.

```
@model List<Vidly.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customer</h2>

<table id="customers" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Customers</th>
            <th scope="col">MembershipType</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var customer in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Edit", "Customer", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                <td>@customer.MembershipType.MembershipTypes</td>
                <td><button data-customers-id="@customer.Id" class="btn-link js-delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>




@section scripts {



    <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#customers .js-delete").on("click",".js-delete", function (e) {

              var button = $(this);
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {

                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                button.parents("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });



    </script>


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current code, you will fail to find the button element, try to change the selector like

```
$("#customers").on("click",".js-delete", function (e) {
    var button = $(this);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {
    });
});
```

or,

```
$("#customers .js-delete").on("click",function (e) {
    var button = $(this);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {
    });
});
```

For using bootbox, you need to use `bootstrap.css` instead of `bootstrap-lumen.css`.

Try

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/Site.css",
            "~/Content/datatables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried both instances and the result remains the same. The page freezes.

Comment: @AhmedBashir What do you mean by freezes? Is there any error in web browser console? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I check the console and nothing appeared until i accidentally pressed enter. The status code was 400 which was bad request. I noticed that the argument for the 'button.attr("data-customer-id")' was miss spelt. Fixing this however still did not resolve the bootbox confirm not appearing. Also, when i say freeze i mean that the page is not responsive. When clicked, none of the buttons work.

Comment: even if i do something as simple as this  '$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#customers .js-delete").on("click", function (e) {
                var button = $(this);
                bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
            });
        }); ' nothing appears

Comment: not sure what i'm missing.  Here's my project https://github.com/Ahmed-Bashir/Vidly.git

Comment: It worked! I did the change but left bootstrap-lumen in there. Did the trick! Thanks @Tao Zhou ! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i just had the same EXACT issue. I just updated the bootstrap version to version 4 :

`update-Package bootstrap -Version 4.3.1`

after that it just worked.